# Why CompletableFuture.supplyAsync return different type than CompletableFuture.thenCompose?

Tags: java, completable-future

My goal is to understand `CompletableFuture`.

My assumption is: Do asynchronous operation where it is necessary, else run everything else on the main thread. So combination of `supplyAsync` and `thenCompose` v.s. `supplyAsync` should be no different in terms of the return type.

My expected result: Using one `supplyAsync` should be enough. We don't need to use `thenCompose` to combine.

My actual result: The return type is wrong, it should be `CompletableFuture<List<Car>>` instead of `CompletableFuture<CompletableFuture<Object>>`.

For brevity, I will only put the `supplyAsync` and `thenCompose`. The `fetchCars()` and `fetchRating(car.id)` is a synchronous operation, doing `stream().filter().map()` stuffs.

This is the working code. It use `supplyAsync` and `thenCompose`. However, I wish not to use `thenCompose` because I think the code logic should be `Synchronous operation` of `fetchCars()` -> then `Asynchronous Operation` of `fetchRating(car.id)` e.g 1 `fetchCars()` -> then 10 `fetchRating(car.id)`.

AsynchronousExample.java

```
package comparison;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchRating;

public class AsynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    CompletableFuture<List<Car>> cfCars = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(FakeDatabase::fetchCars)
            .thenComposeAsync(cars -> {
              List<CompletableFuture<Car>> updatedCars = cars
                      .stream()
                      .map(car -> CompletableFuture
                              .supplyAsync(() -> {
                                System.out.println("fetching id:\t" + car.id);
                                car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
                                return car;
                                // cars.size() & 0x7 equals to maximum 7 threads.
                              }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cars.size() & 0x7)))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

              return CompletableFuture
                      .allOf(updatedCars.toArray(new CompletableFuture[updatedCars.size()]))
                      .thenApplyAsync(v -> updatedCars
                              .stream()
                              .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            });

    cfCars.join().forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");

  }
}
```

Second version without `thenCompose`.

```
package comparison;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchCars;
import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchRating;

public class AsynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    CompletableFuture<List<Car>> cfCars = CompletableFuture
            .supplyAsync(() -> {
              List<Car> cars = fetchCars();
              List<CompletableFuture<Car>> updatedCars = cars
                      .stream()
                      .map(car -> CompletableFuture
                              .supplyAsync(() -> {
                                System.out.println("fetching id:\t" + car.id);
                                car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
                                return car;
                                // cars.size() & 0x7 equals to maximum 7 threads.
                              }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cars.size() & 0x7)))
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());

              return CompletableFuture
                      .allOf(updatedCars.toArray(new CompletableFuture[updatedCars.size()]))
                      .thenApplyAsync(v -> updatedCars
                              .stream()
                              .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                              .collect(Collectors.toList()));
            });

    cfCars.join().forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");

  }
}
```

Comment: `fetchCars` in both versions of the code is run asynchronously, so what do you mean by "I think the code logic should be Synchronous operation of fetchCars()..."? You have two asynchronous operations here, and the convenient way to compose them is to use `thenCompose`. You _can_ compose them manually like you have attempted in the second version, but you'd end up reinventing `thenCompose`.

Comment: @Sweeper I don't think the `fetchCars()` needs to run asynchronously. That's why I think I don't need the `thenCompose`. I ended up with this version because I think it is more readable [SO's question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68768023/why-application-using-completable-supplyasync-with-dedicated-thread-pool-will-no). I posted a different SO because I thought I found a bug `it's not.`

Comment: If you don't want `fetchCars` to be asynchronous, then why did you put it in a `CompletableFuture`? If you did what you did in that question, then there wouldn't be any problems with return types, would there?

Comment: @Sweeper I want to update the `List<Car>` from `fetchCars()` asynchronously. The method I am going to call is `fetchRating(car.id)` which took a long time for each `Car` object to be updated. I think you should try the second version. Putting the `fetchCars()` inside or outside the CompletableFuture does not fix the return type issue.