# Why Application using Completable.supplyAsync with dedicated thread pool will not exit?

Tags: java, multithreading, completable-future

My goal is to understand how to use `CompletableFuture`. I wrote a simple asynchronous operation, e.g building `List<Car>` object. I tried to speed the asynchronous operation with a dedicated thread pool.

My expected result: The asynchronous operation should took less time and exit the application immediately.

My actual result: The asynchronous operation took considerably less time. However, the moment I use the dedicated thread pool, the application will not exit with code 0.

AsynchronousExample.java

```
package comparison;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchCars;
import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchRating;

public class AsynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Car> cars = fetchCars();

    List<CompletableFuture<Car>> cf = cars
            .stream()
            .map(car -> CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> {
                      car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
                      return car;
                    }, Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cars.size() & 0b111)))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    cf.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).forEach(System.out::println);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");

  }
}
```

**TL:DR**

FakeDatabase.java

```
package comparison;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FakeDatabase {
  static List<Car> tableCars = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    tableCars.add(new Car(1, "Fiesta"));
    tableCars.add(new Car(2, "Camry"));
    tableCars.add(new Car(3, "M2"));
    tableCars.add(new Car(4, "BMW"));
    tableCars.add(new Car(5, "Honda"));
  }

  static List<CarRating> tableCarRatings = new ArrayList<>();

  static {
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(1, 7));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(2, 4));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(2, 6));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(3, 8));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(3, 10));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(3, 6));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(4, 8));
    tableCarRatings.add(new CarRating(5, 7));
  }

  static List<Car> fetchCars() {
    simulateDelay();
    return tableCars;
  }

  static double fetchRating(int id) {
    simulateDelay();
    return tableCarRatings
            .stream()
            .filter(carRating -> carRating.id == id)
            .mapToDouble(carRating -> carRating.rating)
            .average()
            .orElse(0);
  }

  static void simulateDelay() {
    try {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
    }
  }

}
```

**EDIT**

My bad, i did not know that the `Executor` needs to be shutdown. I guess it's because they're a `non-daemon` thread pool.

Comment: Hi, if you found a solution, I'd suggest to post it as an answer *and accept your own answer*. I think this will help any others that arrive here!

Comment: I also have a feeling that `cars.stream().map(car -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(..., Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cars.size() & 0b111)))` does not do what you expect! You are creating one thread pool for each car in the stream. What you probably want to do is create 1 thread pool and share it among the `CompletableFuture`s processing cars in the stream. Create the pool *outside* the lambda!

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos you're right. I was not aware of that. This `factory` pattern is really dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because the executor use `non-daemon` threads.

There are 2 solution:

1. `ExecutorService.shutdown()` or
2. `Thread.setDaemon(true)`.

Thread pool with daemon threads.

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cars.size() & 0b111, r -> {
      Thread thread = new Thread(r);
      thread.setDaemon(true);
      return thread;
    });
```

This is the solution which use `ExecutorService.shutdown()`. I think it's more clean and probably avoid the JVM halt issue.

AsynchronousExample.java

```
package comparison;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchCars;
import static comparison.FakeDatabase.fetchRating;

public class AsynchronousExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    List<Car> cars = fetchCars();

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cars.size() & 0b111);

    List<CompletableFuture<Car>> cf = cars
            .stream()
            .map(car -> CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> {
                      car.rating = fetchRating(car.id);
                      return car;
                    }, executor))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<Car> updatedCars = cf.stream().map(CompletableFuture::join).collect(Collectors.toList());

    updatedCars.forEach(System.out::println);

    executor.shutdown();
    executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Took " + (end - start) + "ms");

  }
}
```